# How can I show the updated state?

Tags: reactjs

When I'll click submit, it will save in the firestore, however, I still need to reload the page to update the state. How can I code it in a way that once I'll click submit, it will immediately reflect on the screen without reloading it?

```
const Account = () => {
  const [displayName, setdisplayName] = useState(currentUser.displayName);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(currentUser.address);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(currentUser.id);
      const res = userRef.set(
        {
          displayName,
          address,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          placeholder={currentUser.displayName}
          value={displayName}
          color="secondary"
          required
          onChange={(e) => setdisplayName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          type="text"
          placeholder={currentUser.address}
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyAccount;
```

Comment: Try using `useEffect()`

Comment: @Kundan like wrap my handleSubmit in useEffect()?

Comment: No, use it to update the state.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 1 flag to mark when it submit,use `useState` update value of flag and page will change.

```
const Account = () => {
  const [displayName, setdisplayName] = useState(currentUser.displayName);
  const [address, setAddress] = useState(currentUser.address);
  const [flag,setFlag] = useState(false);

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const userRef = firestore.collection("users").doc(currentUser.id);
      const res = userRef.set(
        {
          displayName,
          address,
        },
        { merge: true }
      );
    setFlag(true); 
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <TextField
          placeholder={currentUser.displayName}
          value={displayName}
          color="secondary"
          required
          onChange={(e) => setdisplayName(e.target.value)}
        />
        <TextField
          type="text"
          placeholder={currentUser.address}
          value={address}
          onChange={(e) => setAddress(e.target.value)}
          required
        />
        <Button type="submit">Submit</Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};


export default MyAccount;
```